# Get title and location where marker points in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I want to get title and description every time user points to a certain location. How can I set title and description prop of particular location by using states?

```
const AddLocation=()=>{
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        
    <MapView style={styles.map}
     initialRegion={{
        latitude:  33.738045,
        longitude: 73.084488,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
        <Marker coordinate = {{latitude:  33.738045,longitude: 73.084488}}
     pinColor = {"red"} 
     title={"title"}
     description={"description"}/>
    </MapView>
        
    </View>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useState` of react. Below is a code snippet of the [sample code](https://snack.expo.dev/nLBxVl9Ts) showing how you can do this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});

const AddLocation = () => {
const [title, setTitle] = useState("Title");
const [desc, setDesc] = useState("this is Description");
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
        latitude:  33.738045,
        longitude: 73.084488,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
          <Marker coordinate = {{latitude:  33.738045,longitude: 73.084488}}
     pinColor = {"red"} 
     title={title}
     description={desc}/>
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }


export default AddLocation;
```